# Laravel on subdomain, web.php not routing

Tags: laravel, web, subdomain

I tested my web.php and it is working.
I even tried it with simple code:

```
Route::get('foo', function () { return 'Hello World'; });
```

and i get a 404 error.

Also: On the subdomain.example.com i get my custom programmed laravel 404 error but on subdomain.example.com/foo i get a 404 apache error.

The apache error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at subdomain.example.com Port 80
```

**Why are my routes not working?**

**Why is there a laravel error on "/" and a (i assume) apache error on "/foo"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Laravel issue, you need to set the Apache configuration file for setting the document root to your Laravel project's public folder.

Comment: Considering this,(for debugging reasons) should "subdomain.example.com/public/foo" work or is it normal that it doesnt?

Comment: Well, it would work if you have proper .htaccess file. If not, you need to do "subdomain.example.com/public/index.php/foo"

Comment: I assume that you have registered "subdomain.example.com" to your hosts right? @OvnIvn

Comment: yes, the subdomain was set up for me. There is another main project on example.com

Comment: Did you add virtual host entry on httpd-vhosts.conf?

Comment: The subdomain was set up by my boss who is very fluent in php but not in laravel, is this laravel specific, and is there a way to check if it was added? i have no acess to the apache server.

Comment: Well, this is obviously not Laravel issue. so Please check the apache configurations. I recommend to check the vhost setting.

Comment: subdomain.example.com/index.php/foo is working now, does this mean the server is setup right?

Comment: Yes. it is set properly but it needs some changes. You need to set AllowOverride All to your apache configuration

Comment: You helped me solve it, thanks a lot you can't believe how happy i am now :)

Comment: Haha. glad to hear that you are happy :) Please accept answer to help me ;)